# Curious-looking inductors

Tags: power-supply, inductor, identification

I was poking around a video amplifier and — in its dual-rail power supply — saw a pair of inductors unlike any inductors I've come across before:

[image: inductor left] [image: inductor right]

(These are the two sides of the same inductor; the other looks the same.)

**What properties is this type of construction trying to achieve?**

By the look of things, these sit between a switch mode supply and a 78xx/79xx-based linear regulator. (Happy to provide more details; just let me know of what kind.)

Answer (score 5):

It's just a multi-turn ferrite bead, used to block high-frequency signals. The multiple turns make it more effective at lower frequencies than normal straight-through beads.

You'd get pretty much the same effect by putting five regular beads in series.

For example, here's a [datasheet from Bourns](https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/fb2000_series.pdf).

Comment: Just came across this Wiki post that had a picture of this same part. Lots of good information. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead